# The data i inserted does not show in the DataBase

Tags: c#, database

[image]

I have an form that looks like that.Whenever I insert the Name and Age into the database and i press Show,it shows me all the entries(including the ones I just entered) but in the dbo.Table it does not update,everytime I try to refresh it gives me an error like this
[image: ![enter image description here]

I created the data base using Add->New Item->Service Base DataBase

This is the code for Inserting data:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sql = "Insert into Elevi(Name,Age) values(@Name,@Age)";
         command = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);
        try
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception a)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
        }


    }
```

This is the code for Showing the data:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sql;
            try
            {
                sql = "Select * from Elevi";
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection);

                dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    int IdCitit = Int32.Parse(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    string NumeCitit = dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    int VarstaCitita = Int32.Parse(dataReader.GetValue(2).ToString());

                    MessageBox.Show($"Nume : {NumeCitit} \n Varsa : {VarstaCitita} \n Id: {IdCitit}");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception Exceptie)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Exceptie.Message);
            }

        }
```

For example, if I have the following input and i Press the button for printing the data it will work just fine [image]
,but after I close the form and check the dbo.Elevi[Data] the new input will not be inserted there

The connection string is : @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TestareDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

I got it from Project->Add new DataSource

Comment: Please, paste the code and tell where problem occurs. Don't post images, instead post relevant information formatted as text. Also, include more details, like what technology you use (WinForms, Sql Server, etc.).

Comment: 'Name' is not a good name for a column; try quoting it '[Name]'

Comment: Also, separate your DB code out of teh button click....

Comment: Please show your connection string. It's not unlikely the problem is there.

Comment: You mean using functions for the DB code and then call those in the button code?

Comment: Could you try and replace `|DataDirectory|` in your connection string with the actual physical path, and re-run your tests? Just to rule out a potential misconfiguration.

Answer (score -1):

I think you code is not wrong, it seams like it is a database error. Perhaps the database file was created with a newer version of SQL Server Express than the one installed on your machine? Your SQL tools in VS are not compatible with the SQL server. Check the versions of the SQL tools.

Answer (score -1):

Usually it happens when transaction doesn't get committed and it remains in memory, thus if we check the values by using same connection then we find latest one but when we try to verify it from table by using other connection we don't find it unless program commits the transaction.

try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnection))
    {
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("MyTransaction");

        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        try
        {
            command.CommandText = $"Insert into Elevi(Name,Age) values({textBox1.Text},{textBox2.Text})";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception a)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your comment should not be a comment; it should be part of the answer. Please edit the answer.